# How to append a new diagram below of current Highstock diagram?

Tags: highcharts

I need to add new diagram below of current diagram in Highstock. For example I have this diagram:
[image]

How can I add new diagram into this digram?
[image]

The new diagram is synced to the older one and I don't want to draw new diagram in a new html div. See the red line in 2nd image.

Comment: I would suggest to use two separate charts , and sync them using `afterSetExtremes` event. However, you can achieve above in one chart using more panes in the chart. The same way you did it for "volume" in the top one.

Comment: I wanna use the same way I did it for "volume" in the top one. But How can I do it in new ajax request? It means I need to append new diagram after first has drawn.

Comment: So, when new data comes, try to use [`addAxis()`](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#Chart.addAxis) and [`addSeries()`](http://api.highcharts.com/highstock#Chart.addSeries). Like this: http://jsfiddle.net/pr8do9c3/

Comment: Please view this link: http://memvoo.com/stockprofile/35366681030756042 
and click on 'English' in header to change language. Then click on 'Technical analysis' 3rd item in side bar. then in 'Tools' > 'Indicators' click on 'ADX' and in popup click 'Draw Chart'. I want this. Thank you very much.

Comment: Ok and then see my comment above again. `addAxis()` and `addSeries()` is a way to go. Remember, that you can set `Axis.top` and `Axis.height` in percents. The same way as in your first screenshot.

Comment: PS: The same way I'm adding axes in the [Indicators plugin](http://blacklabel.github.io/indicators/). [Here](https://github.com/blacklabel/indicators/blob/master/js/indicators.js#L990) you can find method to do so.

Comment: I used `Axis.top` and `addAxis()` and `addSeries()` : 
`var chart = $('.diagram').highcharts();
        chart.addAxis({ // Secondary yAxis
            id: 'rainfall-axis',
            lineWidth: 1,
            opposite: true,
            top: '100%',
            offset: 5,
        });
        chart.addSeries({
            name: 'Rainfall',
            type: 'line',
            color: '#08F',
            yAxis: 'rainfall-axis',
            data: newData
        });`
but result is [link](http://i59.tinypic.com/zjxe9y.jpg) my new diagram is out of div.

Comment: Because you set `top:100%` ? It's outside the div. I suggest to set `top: "80%", height:"10%"` . Of course, don't forget to update all other axis heights and tops..